# Query Regarding Mumps

Tags: mumps

What is the meaning of `S Z%%=Z(,"Z")` this statement?

Answer (score 5):

This statement is not Standard MUMPS.  The variable name Z%% is not a valid local variable name. The local array Z must be subscripted by actual values. There is no expression between the open parenthesis and the comma, which must be defined in valid MUMPS syntax.